# React changing value of object change order of array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, rendering, state

I'm kinda new to React and i try to figure out how to change the state of my object's. But when i change the state in my input field the field is rerenderd at the bottom.

How can i keep my input field on the same place as it's renders the first time.

```js
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        persons: [{
            id: 0,
            name: ''
        },{
            id: 1,
            name: ''
        }]
    }
    
    changePersonNameHandler = event => {
        const id = parseInt(event.target.id);
        const newPersonName = event.target.value;

        this.setState({
            persons: [...this.state.persons.filter(i => i.id !== id),
                {
                    id,
                        name: newPersonName,
                }
            ]
        })
    }
    
    render () {
        const {persons} = this.state;
        
        return (
          <div>
            <ul>
              {persons.map((i, index)  => (
                  <li key={i.id}>
                      <label>Name: </label>
                      <input id={i.id}
                           value={i.name}
                           onChange{this.changePersonNameHandler}/>
                  </li>
                  )
              )}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` removes an item and you lose its position. To modify an item and keep its place in the array use `map`.
Also it is better not rely on `this.state` to get a new value for `setState`. You should use `setState(oldState => newState)` instead.

```
changePersonNameHandler = event => {
    const id = parseInt(event.target.id);
    const newPersonName = event.target.value;

    this.setState(old => {
        const persons = old.persons.map(
            person => person.id !== id ? person : {id, name: newPersonName}
        );
        return {persons};
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Each time you're doing a change, you put the edited person at the end of the array** in your handleChange method.

**Just invert the edited one and the existing ones** in setState and it will do the trick.

```
this.setState({
  persons: [{
      id,
      name: newPersonName,
    }, 
    ...this.state.persons.filter(i => i.id !== id)
    ]
  })
}
```

- There is a missing `=` sign after `onChange` in the code you gave but I guess in your local code it's ok.